# why getting 504 response code after method terminates successfully?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, http-status-code-504

I'm working on a Java app using spring(v4.3.13.RELEASE), spring-boot(v1.5.9.RELEASE) and Hibernate(5.4.12.Final).
also using postgres(not sure its version) as db.

I have a problem, when this backend app gets a REST call, it executing a big method, that first is querying postgres to get all user data. sometimes it can be a lot of data returned, represented by hibernate objects.
Then, this method is performing some logic on this data and save it to the db.
so far so good.

I have a user that when I get request from, it seems that everything is working well,
logs are printed as usual, no errors during the method execution, then result is returned as normal and after then an exception is raise in the app -

`java.io.IOException: Broken pipe` (full stackTrace is below)

so the response returned is failure with status code 504 (instead of 'success' with code 200).

It happens also when only reading data from db and not writing to it.
all code blocks that are reading/writing to db are surrounded by try/catch blocks.

I don't know what is causing this error since it seems that method execution is terminated successfully and no errors pops up during execution and execution time is also fine (approximately 5 min).
I tried to increase hibernate default db transactions timeout in my app (was 10 min and i changed it to 1.5 hours!) but it doesn't seems to help because method execution is terminating successfully.

any thoughts and help would be appreciated!!!!

````
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:356)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:815)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2039)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1051)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:953)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:286)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:231)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1034)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at io.micrometer.spring.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1267)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:450)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:388)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:644)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:121)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:235)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:351)
    ... 83 common frames omitted```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

The above line of your exception means the client made a request to the server, but probably before the server could produce the response, send it back and close the connection, the client for some reason decided to close the connection himself.

Therefore the server understands that the connection is not anymore open and hence the error saying Broken pipe, meaning the server can't transmit the data any more even if the response is ready.

One case where this would be possible to happen often is if the client was some system with some timeout configuration which outmatched the server response time.

Comment: Hi!
I understand what is the meaning of the exception. but there is no system in "middle" between backend and db. the execution is fine, no errors during execution, response is returned and then this error pops up. backend timeout configuration is increased also.

Comment: @Jessi your backend timeout configuration should not be related with this issue. Maybe there is a system in middle between client and server, maybe a proxy server